# Mean of Beta distribution without using Gamma function?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, special-functions, beta-function

Is there a way to prove directly that

$$\int_0^1x^{(\alpha+1)-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}dx=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}\int_0^1x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}dx$$

without reference to the fact that

$$\int_0^1x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}dx=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}$$

or any other Gamma function facts?

---

I tried using integration by parts, but of course differentiating $x^{(\alpha+1)-1}$ meant that I had to integrate $(1-x)^{\beta-1}$, so I only managed to prove that

$$\int_0^1x^{(\alpha+1)-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}dx=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\int_0^1x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{(\beta+1)-1}dx\text{.}$$

Comment: If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are known integers then you can keep going with integration by parts until you exhaust one of them.  At which point you will have something what looks close to a binomial coefficient.  You might then be willing to short cut this for general integers.

Comment: You have
$$
\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 x^{\alpha-1} (1-x)^{\beta-1} \, dx = B(\alpha,\beta) \\ \\
& \int_0^1 x\cdot x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1} \,dx = B(\alpha+1,\beta) \\ \\
\text{and so }& \int_0^1 x\cdot \frac{x^{\alpha-1} (1-x)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha,\beta)} = \frac{B(\alpha+1,\beta)}{B(\alpha,\beta)}
\end{align}
$$
So the question is how to derive the functional equation $$B(\alpha+1,\beta) = \dfrac \alpha {\alpha+\beta} B(\alpha, \beta)$$ directly from the integrals above  without using any integrals involving exponential functions. $\qquad$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\frac{d}{dx}x^\alpha(1-x)^\beta = \left(\alpha-(\alpha+\beta) x\right)x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{b-1}$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\left(\alpha-(\alpha+\beta) x\right)x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}\,dx = 0 $$
which implies
$$ (\alpha+\beta)\int_{0}^{1}x^\alpha(1-x)^{\beta-1}\,dx = \alpha\int_{0}^{1}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}\,dx $$
as wanted.

Answer (score 2):

What you've got is enough: you can write
$$ x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1+1} = x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}(1-x) = x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}-x^{\alpha+1-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}. $$
Thus combining this with the formula in the question,
$$ B(\alpha+1,\beta) = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}B(\alpha,\beta+1) = \frac{\alpha}{\beta}(B(\alpha,\beta)-B(\alpha+1,\beta)) $$
and you can rearrange this to get the desired formula.

Comment: Doesn't this only show that $B(\alpha,\beta+1)=B(\alpha,\beta)-B(\alpha+1,\beta)$?

Comment: It does show that. Combine that with the formula you found.